# Manager of groups stopped appearing as member and groups stopped appearing in her "my groups" list

Tags: 7, database, organic-groups, users

I'm utterly befuddled.

I'm in the process of building a site (D7) that is group-based. I have a few users on the site right now as I develop it and try to work out bugs. One of my users had created several groups, joined a couple others, and everything worked fine until sometime between yesterday and today. Suddenly, the groups she started (and is therefore manager of) stopped showing in her list of groups she is a member of. At the same time, she lost non-manager memberships of all groups but one, and then whenever she added a group it removed the prior one.

I had (and continue to have) the number of groups someone can join set to unlimited. I've also gotten it so she can be a member of more than one group again. However, groups she's a manager of still don't appear on her list, and her name doesn't appear on the members list on those group pages. When she views the groups she's manager of, it does say "You are the group manager." That relationship doesn't seem to appear anywhere else, though.

To further add to the confusion, on my non-admin account on the site I am manager on one group and member of another. I never lost visibility of my group I manage, and it never lost visibility of me. This seems to have affected only her account.

I'm at a loss to figure out what happened and how to solve it. I did back up the db yesterday morning (before whatever broke this happened), although I've had 2 new users and have made other adjustments since then. Can I compare her uid in the two databases and manually correct differences? Where would I look to set elements of group membership/management? Is there an easier way to do this just through Drupal admin interface?

Comment: I tried this as an answer, but disallowed for several more hours: 

Apparently the user was still manager of her groups, but was no longer registered as a member. I was able to use the Masquerade module to assume her identity, go to the appropriate node/%/group menus for each one she was manager of and give her membership again. Everything seems to be back in line after that. 

My guess is it was caused by overzealous use of an alternate link/rule set I was experimenting with to manage group enrollments/drops. I've now disabled that until I figure out how to get to function properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the user was still manager of her groups, but was no longer registered as a member. I was able to use the Masquerade module to assume her identity, go to the appropriate node/%/group menus for each one she was manager of and give her membership again. Everything seems to be back in line after that. My guess is it was caused by overzealous use of an alternate link/rule-set I was experimenting with to manage group enrollments/drops. I've now disabled that until I figure out how to get to function properly.